# How to install HP Printer on Ubuntu 20.04 using hplip

Tags: printing, hplip

Searching at Google I see several options to install my HP printer, including starting the HPLIP installation, but I understand that Ubuntu 20.04 already brings HPLIP installed, version 3.20
So I understand the best option is with the command **hp-setup**
is the best option to install my HP printer?

Comment: please read [ask] and then [edit] your question with further details such as what you have tried so far and what errors (if any) you have encountered when printing. A note of your printer model might also help the community to address your question.

Comment: What is your printer model name? Did you already try to run `hp-setup` from HPLIP?

Comment: My printer is HP Deskjet p1005 but dont have yet my new Dell xps 13 laptop. Im looking for any advice in order to avoid problems when install the printer

Comment: I understand I have to open terminal and just **sudo hp-setup**

Comment: `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` followed by `hp-setup` and `hp-plugin` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice